# OnChange event for elements in html set with DangerouslySetInnerHTML in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a json file with HTML Element (more than 20) details like, id, value, type, etc.

I am creating a big String with all the elements created and inserting it into my React JS component with 'DangerouslySetInnerHTML'. But, I want to use onChange event on these events.

```
finalStartingElementStructure += 'onChange=' + '"'  + this.onChangeForAllElements + '"';

onChangeForAllElements(e) {
    // console.log('onChange INVOKED', e);
  }
```

This is not working for sure, but, I am out of options for calling onChange event on requirement.

I am a noob in React JS, please shed some light on it.

Comment: Why creating a string instead of letting React creating the elements?

Comment: The Json file which has my elements will keep on changing, its more like I am creating a HTML snippet by parsing through the JSON file

Comment: Take a look at his, I think this will solve your problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805713/avoid-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-when-wrapping-html-in-react-js?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for responding but, I am not looking to replace DangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that always work is using jQuery, ReactJS and jQuery are working well together. The following solution also works for dynamically generated elements.

```
$(document).on('change', 'your-selector', this.onChangeForAllElements);

onChangeForAllElements(e) {
   // console.log('onChange INVOKED', e);
}
```

But if you want to use React functionality I recommend to use the React way to create elements instead of using the insecure DangerouslySetInnerHTML method.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, what if I dont want to mention 'your-selector' static, i.e., is there a way where I can mention something like this, call this method onChange event.

Comment: So, you create your HTML snippet while parsing through the JSON. You could also call the jQuery thing there with a dynamic selector – while parsing through, there you have the id, you said.
But – alternatively – and as I understand you – all elements that are created should have the same event, right? Then your selector could be the descendant selector on a common parent, then it could be maybe static.

Comment: Can you please share a sample code so that I can understand a bit more clearly

Comment: The following selector will select all children of an element with id parent: ``#parent *``. I don't know your exact setup, but #parent could be the element with the method DangerouslySetInnerHTML. 
If you want to add the event listener while parsing, just do something like this (assumed that you parse the JSON file inside of the respective React component, so variable ``this`` is available): ``$(document).on('change', '#'+id, this.onChangeForAllElements);``

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped :) only thing is on change is called twice for every element, any idea why?

Comment: I don't know how you exactly implemented it. But to debug it you should console.log which element's change event is called and when. events will be delegated and bubbled – so ``e.preventDefault()`` could be an solution, or ``e.stopPropagation()``. Another option is that you assign the event twice to the same element what can happen if the parsing method is called twice and the elements have the same ids. But with ``$(document).off`` you can remove event listener before.